# python module not found.. i have already installed the module tho

Tags: python

i have no idea what is wrong i all using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pip is linked to Python 3.10, not 3.11

I suggest you use `python3.11 -m pip install flask`, or more preferably, use a venv